# How to return data in JSON format from handsontable?

Tags: json, handsontable

I am just planning to purchase this component. The most basic thing, we were looking is, whether handsontable returns data in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does.

Here is how I get data from the table in JSON:

```
JSON.stringify($("#tableDIV").data("handsontable").getData());
```

Hope this helps.